# Table cells lose spacing when inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, cellpadding

I'm building a web app using HTML & SVG, and I've run into a weird problem with tables. When I move my table into a particular div, all the cells lose their spacing.

This is my expected result:

[image: Intended result]

This is what I actually get:

[image: The habitruler table loses all spacing between cells]

To achieve the expected result, I put my table 'habitruler' inside 'main' but above 'habits':

[image: Current HTML structure that achieves intended result]

What I want to do though is put 'habitruler' inside 'habits' like this:

[image: Desired HTML structure]

All I'm doing is moving it inside another div, but the moment I do that all the spacing disappears between cells as you see in image #2.

This is the css for the div 'habits':

[image: CSS for habits]

And this is the table inside 'habitruler':

[image: habitruler's html structure]

This even happens when I remove all the other child elements from 'habits'. I can't find anything out of the ordinary that would cause this. I also can't find any information on tables that would explain this behaviour. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening, or what I can try next to find out?

Comment: _"This is the css for the div 'habits':"_ - that's of rather little interest. What you should check, is what makes those cells have that spacing in the _working_ version.

Comment: Also, before you ask the next time, please go read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: CBroe thanks for the suggestion. I decided to check the computed styles of both versions, first the table, then the table cell. It looks like inside #habits the table cells become inline-blocks rather than table-cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`habitruler` maybe inherits style from `habits`, try  `!important`

(also show css from devtools for habitruler)

Comment: where would !important go?

Comment: style="padding: 0px 30px !important;"

Comment: The table cells were inheriting a style from #habits. I had to check the computed styles of both versions and discovered the cell's display style was going from table-cell to inline-block. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
table{ table-layout:fixed; width: 100%;}
```

If it doesn't solve the problem please show what's styling  and  is having. So, I can propose better solution.

Comment: I'm already using those styles for the table. I think I've found the issue though. Thanks for the suggestion!